# Stuck Setting up libc6:i386

Tags: debugging, gdb, dbg

I'm currently setting up a debugger, but no matter attempts I tried it keeps getting stuck on setting up lib6:i386.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libc6:i386 (2.37-12) ...
```

I have tried doing

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

It kept stuck on setting up lib6:i386. Any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't shown _any_ problems. What is your _actual_ problem?

Comment: it kept stuck on setting up lib6:i386 for whatever package i install